# create canvas element and delete (Angular 2+)

Tags: angular, canvas

I have the following worked code snippet in javascript. I'm not able to get the element by `document.getElementById()` in Angular 2+. Is there another way?

```
var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
canv.id = 'canvas';

var oldcanv = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this @ViewChild to get an element by id here an example.

HTML

```
<canvas #canvas width="200" height="200" >         
</canvas>
```

Component

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'canvas-anim',
  templateUrl: './canvas-anim.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-anim.component.css']
})
export class CanvasAnimComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
    ctx: any;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.ctx  = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');         
        this.paint(this.ctx);        
    }

    paint(ctx){ 

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Here a reference of game engine developed in angular 2 [Space Invaders](https://github.com/AbelValdez/Angular2-Space-Invaders/blob/master/app/Scene/CanvasScene.component.ts) inside you will see a lot of painting techniques.